# How do I make an EventSetter in the App.xaml file in WPF?

Tags: wpf, textbox, app.xaml, eventsetter

I want every TextBox in my application to select all its text when the user focuses on it.  To do this, I put the following in my App.xaml file:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" x:Key="tbkey">
        <EventSetter Event="GotFocus" Handler="textBoxFocus"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

and the following code in the App.xaml.cs file:

```
private void textBoxFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs a)
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        t.SelectAll();
    }
```

However, the method is never called when a TextBox is focused in my application.  I think it is because I am not putting the handler method in the right location but I have no idea where that would be.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Remove **x:Key="tbkey"** and your textBoxFocus method will be fired.

**EDIT**

> Source Code can be downloaded
>   [**here**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1719731/STO/WpfApplication5.zip)

Comment: That did not solve the problem.  The x:Key was originally not in there but I put it there in hopes that it would make it work.

Comment: I've created a sample application for you to prove that its working. See EDIT. Thanks